# BulkAPI error while uploading multiple attachments

Tags: bulk-api

I am trying to upload multiple attachments using Bulk API. I am using `createBatchFromDir()` for creating the Batch & using the sample code provided in the sfdc documentation at the link:-

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm.

I have replaced the `createBatchesFromCSVFile()` method with `createBatchFromDir()`.

I am passing the `batchContent` parameter as

```
InputStream batchContent = new FileInputStream("C://Temp//TestUploadCases//Attachments//Upload.csv");
```

Also have set the ContentType param as "ZIP_CSV".

However when I execute the code I am getting the following error:-

BATCH STATUS:

```
[BatchInfo  id=........
 jobId=.........
 state='Failed'
 stateMessage='InvalidBatch : Field name not found : Name'
...
]
```

> [AsyncApiException  exceptionCode='InvalidBatch'
> exceptionMessage='Records not processed' ]

This error occurs while trying to execute the following line in `checkResults()` method:-

```
new CSVReader(connection.getBatchResultStream(job.getId(), b.getId()));
```

Any help to resolve the above error would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The header contains 3 colmns as:- Name ParentId Body

Answer (score 1):

I provided the Zip file path as `tmpInpuStream` and got the same error by calling:

```
connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);
```

(Same Error)

Provided the path of manifest file as request.txt by calling:

```
connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);
```

(Same Error)

After analyzing the Apex Data Loader functionality, I provided the path of manifest file as `request.csv` and calling: (It worked)

```
connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);
```

bypassing `createCSVFromBatches()` method and the Name in Manifest file matching the Key of attachments Map.

Also, the value of attachments Map containing the absolute path of File and Body of manifest file containing the relative path using #.

Answer (score -1):

May be for successful result you need add 'Name' column in your csv.
Is it possible to show your csv-file header (column names)?

Answer (score -1):

Please check Field level security and profile settings of the field,and compare with userprofile you are executing this job with